# Cache images in with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

Suppose I have webapp in which there are 1000 images like,

```
<img src="something" />
<img src="something" />
<img src="something" />
.
.
.
<img src="something" />
```

Which makes page loading slower, as that each image is retrieved from the request and displayed to the page.

My question is that , Is there is any other way to minimize page loading time.

What I have tried is that I tried to encode these images with base64 but it is increasing the size of the webpage.

Any guidance , help appreciated.

Comment: Many sites these days will only begin rendering off-screen images when a user scrolls past a certain point, or even clicks a "more" button or some such.  Alternatively, you could use an AJAX call to load them asychronously.

Comment: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22888/Caching-Images-in-ASP-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22888/Caching-Images-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?  Are the images being re-loaded on *every* request to the page from the same user?  (In which case caching is an option.)  Or are you talking about a slow *initial* page load?  (In which case caching won't help because the images aren't known to the browser yet.)  And no, changing the encoding won't do anything.  You still need to transfer the data from the server to the client, there's really no way around that.

Comment: if individual images are small, consider "Image Sprites" - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! provides a good list of optimization techniques for a web site. Check this link out (https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

In your case 1000 images is a lot for a page.
consider breaking the page into multiple pages and let the user to switch them with paginations.

If everything has to be on the same page, then consider delayed loading. The images are loaded only after the html is loaded. This can be combined with loading on scroll, as suggested by ne1410s. As User scrolls down, the new images are loaded. (Jquery has plugins for this type of loading. Here's one http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Consider optimizing your site in other areas as well (it will give you extra performance too). For example, cache the images in users browser. When they return to your site, these images are not downloaded again from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Consider lazy-loading, images will only be loaded on demand (when the page is scrolled).

Scott Hanselman made [an interesting article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PinchingPenniesWhenScalingInTheCloud.aspx) on how he save money in the cloud by using lazy-loaders.

> The easy solution was to lazy load the images as the user scrolls,
>   thereby only using bandwidth for the images you see. I looked at Mike
>   Tupola's jQuery LazyLoad plugin as well as a number of other similar
>   scripts. There's also Luis Almeida's lightweight Unveil if you want
>   fewer bells and whistles. I ended up using the standard Lazy Load.

Lazy-load libraries are very easy to use, for example:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
      $("img.lazy").lazyload({effect: "fadeIn"});
  });
</script>
```

Apart from that make sure all your image are optimized for the Web, the size/quality is correct and use sprites if you images are static and cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying over 1000 images your are doing something wrong in your design. There is no good reason to show over 1000 images on one page, or on the initial page.